# Победить - вот мечта Ольги? - Где подлежащее в предложении?

Tags: синтаксис

Где подлежащее в предложении *Победить - вот мечта Ольги*?

Answer (score 4):

Подлежащее- "победить".

Победить - это что?-это мечта.

Можно перестроить: Победить является мечтой.